# Why is the width.cutoff argument in the deparse function limited to 500 bytes?

Tags: r

Why is the `width.cutoff` argument in `deparse` limited to 500 bytes?

Consider the following reproducible example:

```
a <- substitute(12345.6789 * x0 + 123523.623529 * x1 + 1235235.6734636 * x2
     + 657567.6756756 * x3 + 756765.23523 * x4 + 54645.65464 * x5)
deparse(a)
[1] "12345.6789 * x0 + 123523.623529 * x1 + 1235235.6734636 * x2 + "
[2] "    657567.6756756 * x3 + 756765.23523 * x4 + 54645.65464 * x5"
```

The default value of `width.cutoff` is `60`, meaning that the function will attempt to split the character string into 60 character chunks. If you specify the argument to an integer above `500`, you get the following error:

```
deparse(a, width.cutoff = 501)
[1] "12345.6789 * x0 + 123523.623529 * x1 + 1235235.6734636 * x2 + "
[2] "    657567.6756756 * x3 + 756765.23523 * x4 + 54645.65464 * x5"
Warning message:
In deparse(a, width.cutoff = 501) :
  invalid 'cutoff' value for 'deparse', using default
```

I could understand if the default was set to 60 because of some concern about storing a massive character string in memory. However, I don't understand why I am not allowed to set this argument to `1000` or `10000`. Why is there an upper bound on the number of characters that deparse can return in a single string?

R can clearly create a string with more than 500 characters.

```
nchar(paste(rep('a', 1000), collapse = ''))
[1] 1000
```

I tried to understand what was going on by going to the source code [on github](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/deparse.c). I found this hilarious comment

> The previous issue with the global "cutoff" variable is now implemented
>   by creating a deparse1WithCutoff() routine which takes the cutoff from
>   the caller and passes this to the different routines as a member of the
>   LocalParseData struct. Access to the deparse1() routine remains unaltered.
>   This is exactly as Ross had suggested ...
>
> One possible fix is to restructure the code with another function which
>   takes a cutoff value as a parameter.   Then "do_deparse" and "deparse1"
>   could each call this deeper function with the appropriate argument.
>   I wonder why I didn't just do this? -- it would have been quicker than
>   writing this note.  I guess it needs a bit more thought ...

Before I dive deeper into the source code, can someone explain to me why there is an upper bound on this argument? Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I thi "why" questions should be directed at the author of the code.